# Hbase bulk load with google cloud storage

Tags: hbase, google-cloud-storage

I have a service that need to read data from GCS and insert to Hbase. My plan is uses hbase bulk load, after create hfiles and store them on GCS, I run command

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles -Dhbase.zookeeper.quorum="hbase-host" -Dzookeeper.znode.parent="/hbase" -Dhbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181 -Dcreate.table=no gs://hbase-location hbase-table
```

But it gives me an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2665)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:93)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2701)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2683)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:372)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.discoverLoadQueue(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:941)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.prepareHFileQueue(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:331)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.run(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:1172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.run(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:1210)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.tool.LoadIncrementalHFiles.main(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:1232)
```

Has anyone ever run into the same problem?  Is there any way to config for hbase such as

```
conf.set("fs.gs.impl", classOf[com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem].getName)
```